# How to protect worksheets in XSSFWorkbook using Apache poi library?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to protect worksheets in XSSFWorkbook using Apache poi library? I saw many solutions on SO and other sites but they are old or not working.

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
  </dependency>
```

Below is the sample code:

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new  XSSFWorkbook(FILE_NAME);
        XSSFSheet s = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        s.enableLocking();
        s.lockDeleteColumns(true);
        s.protectSheet("password");

        workbook.lockStructure();
        workbook.close();
```

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to the latest stable version?

Comment: I have tried upgrading to new version as well, can you suggest a version and sample working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying for hours I found the issue and it was very stupid mistake.
workbook does not update itself, instead we have to create new workbook which will have the protected sheet.